# Apache Tomcat 10 not showing in Eclipse Runtime Envirionments

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I installed Tomcat 10 but Eclipse only shows up to Tomcat 8, my Eclipse version is 2020-12 (4.18.0). I downloaded the most recent version of the JST server adapters but it still doesn't show version 10 [here's a printscreen showing that there is no Tomcat 10 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgjG7.png)

Comment: How did you download and install "the most recent version of the JST server adapters"?

Comment: using the eclipse marketplace

Comment: Can you be more specific? It looks like you have a really, really old version of it, then.

Comment: Install the new version from Eclipse's release site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12` (Help > Install New Software)

Comment: it worked, did not even realised my eclipse was outdated, thanks for pointing this out